# Getting 1 decimal place from summarise when option "digits" is set to 7

Tags: r, dplyr, rstudio

When I divide `68/70` then take `* 100` at the command line I get `97.14286` but when I include that formula in `summarise(perc_survived = (survived/N)*100)` the output is `97.1`. Why is that so?
I checked `getOption("digits")` and got back `7`. The output column is labeled as `double`, so why the truncated decimal place?

`summarise(N = n(), survived = sum(Survived), perc_survived = (survived/N)*100)`

Comment: If you could share your data it will make it easier for people to help you

Comment: This works ok for me, `data.frame(survived = 68, N = 70)%>% summarise(new = (survived/N)*100)`  - `97.14286`

Comment: Aha...but this gets me `97.1`... `tibble(survived = 68, N = 70)%>% summarise(new = (survived/N)*100)`

Answer (score 2):

It is just *tibble* print formatting, see below:

```
identical(
  tibble(survived = 68, N = 70) %>% summarise(new = (survived/N)*100) %>% .$new,
  68/70 * 100
  )
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Or... `%>% pull(new)` :)